# Groovy strange notation

Tags: grails, groovy

I downloaded the Camel project (http://camel.apache.org/) written in Groovy and notice a file with a strange notation:

`package ${package}`

and in another project similar thing:

`package org.codenarc.rule.${ruleCategory}`

As far I know this is not valid in Groovy syntax. Is there a special tool to deal with this?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Those look like groovy template files

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Templates

So those files are used to generate other groovy source files